# Can't download install an iso file for Windows in a USB stick with WoeUSB

Tags: usb, mount, woeusb

Whenever I try it says:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@  
==============================  
Error: Target device is currently busy, unmount all mounted partitions in target device then try again
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 512: 31020 Terminated              
while true; do  
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Target device is busy, please make sure you unmount all filesystems on target device before detaching it.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WoeUSB requires that the target device (the USB drive that you inserted) be unmounted before it can write anything to it. Open the Disks application, select the USB device that you inserted in the left pane of Disks and unmount it. Click the black square marked by a red arrow in the below screenshot to unmount the selected partition.

[image]

Comment: were can i find it?

Comment: In the Dash type *disks* and click on the Disks icon, a gray hard drive with a wrench on top of it, to open the Disks application. Then you will see something that looks like the screenshot in my answer under where it says **Volumes**.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this error, and another option for those who prefer CLI:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Find the disk and device (partition) that is appropriate. In my case the disk was `/dev/sdb`, and the device (partition) was `/dev/sdb1`.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

then re-attempt the install from WoeUSB.

Answer (score 1):

For people who can't get rid of this or another issue, [here](https://dev.to/tgotwig/flash-usb-stick-for-windows-from-ubuntu-1la8) is a how-to with `unetbootin`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your result :-) How did you install the Windows installer? Please describe the method with more details (step by step). For example, did you use WoeUSB, in that case how did you install it? Or did you simply extract the content from the iso file to the NTFS file system?

Comment: Wrote a small articel on dev.to  https://dev.to/tgotwig/create-bootable-usb-stick-for-windows-from-macos-104m, I think I could write another one with Ubuntu & WoeUSB 

Comment: Yes, I think it would make your answer useful, if you make it as detailed as that artiticle. Of course you should check that it really works with the current versions of the involved software *all the way* before publishing it.

Comment: Thanks for the new article :-) Please edit your answer here to not only link to your web-site, but also copy your text and pictures into the answer here to make it a complete answer.